# Parse certain string values surrounded by brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to extract certain string values surrounded by special characters like brackets and create new columns using the extracted string values. For example, the original column looks like this.

```
         Column
Dec12 SKLEKF [[ABC]] <<JK>>
Jan13 KEJ [[FJ]] <<UHJ>>
FEB12 JKEJSKEJG [[GBC]] <<JUIDJ>>
```

I'm trying to create two new columns using the string values within the brackets. The new data table should look like this.

```
Code     ID
ABC      JK
FJ       UHJ
GBC      JUIDJ
```

I tried the following code but it is not working because the length of the string values that come before the brackets and within the brackets varies by row. Is there any way to parse the string values surrounded by the brackets regardless of their length?

```
select SUBSTRING(Column, 13, 3) AS Code
from table
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use `charindex` or `patindex` to determine the start and end of the substring. There are lots of examples of people doing this available.

Comment: I vote for extracting what you want outside of SQL Server and then importing a clean CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

Using `SUBSTRING` operations:

```sql
SELECT
    col,
    SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('[[', col) + 2,
              CHARINDEX(']]', col) - CHARINDEX('[[', col) - 2) AS Code,
    SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('<<', col) + 2,
              CHARINDEX('>>', col) - CHARINDEX('<<', col) - 2) AS ID
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method by using XML and XQuery.

The idea is to tokenize a string of tokens, and get individual tokens based on their position: `[last()]` and `[last()-1]`.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (seq INT identity PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Dec12 SKLEKF [[ABC]] <<JK>>'),
('Jan13 KEJ [[FJ]] <<UHJ>>'),
('FEB12 JKEJSKEJG [[GBC]] <<JUIDJ>>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , TRIM('[]' FROM c.value('(/root/r[last()-1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')) AS Code
    , TRIM('<>' FROM c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')) AS ID
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(tokens, SPACE(1), ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-----+-----------------------------------+------+-------+
| seq |              tokens               | Code |  ID   |
+-----+-----------------------------------+------+-------+
|   1 | Dec12 SKLEKF [[ABC]] <<JK>>       | ABC  | JK    |
|   2 | Jan13 KEJ [[FJ]] <<UHJ>>          | FJ   | UHJ   |
|   3 | FEB12 JKEJSKEJG [[GBC]] <<JUIDJ>> | GBC  | JUIDJ |
+-----+-----------------------------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: This works as long as the portions are in the expected position. Although the given example gives this impression I'd prefer a more *tolerant* approach...

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion:

```
SELECT A.casted.value('(/x/@code)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Code
      ,A.casted.value('(/x/@id)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS I
      ,A.casted
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.tokens,'[[','<x code="')
                                                                ,']]','"/>')
                                                                ,'<<','<x id="')
                                                                ,'>>','"/>') AS xml))) A(casted)
```

The idea in short:

- As your are using different "markup" characters we can easily transform your string to valid XML doing some replacements
  The result `Dec12 SKLEKF <x code="ABC" /><x id="JK" />`
- Now it is easy to grab the attribute's values with `.value()` directly from the XML.

**UPDATE**

If your codes might include characters forbidden within XML you can use this `APPLY` instead:

```
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT t.tokens AS [*] FOR XML PATH(''))
                                                                ,'[[','<x code="')
                                                                ,']]','"/>')
                                                                ,'&lt;&lt;','<x id="')
                                                                ,'&gt;&gt;','"/>') AS xml))) A(casted);
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it:

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (seq INT identity PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Dec12 SKLEKF [[ABC]] <<JK>>'),
('Jan13 KEJ [[FJ]] <<UHJ>>'),
('FEB12 JKEJSKEJG [[GBC]] <<JUIDJ>>');

-- DDL and sample data population, end    
SELECT 
  Seq    = t.seq,
  Tokens = t.tokens,
  [Code] = SUBSTRING(t.tokens,a1.Pos+2,a2.Pos-a1.Pos-2),
  [ID]   = SUBSTRING(t.tokens,b1.Pos+2,b2.Pos-b1.Pos-2)
FROM        @tbl                                       AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('[[',t.tokens)))         AS a1(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('<<',t.tokens)))         AS b1(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(']',t.tokens,a1.Pos+2))) AS a2(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('>',t.tokens,b1.Pos+2))) AS b2(Pos);
```

**Returns:**

```
+-----+-----------------------------------+------+-------+
| seq |              tokens               | Code |  ID   |
+-----+-----------------------------------+------+-------+
|   1 | Dec12 SKLEKF [[ABC]] <<JK>>       | ABC  | JK    |
|   2 | Jan13 KEJ [[FJ]] <<UHJ>>          | FJ   | UHJ   |
|   3 | FEB12 JKEJSKEJG [[GBC]] <<JUIDJ>> | GBC  | JUIDJ |
+-----+-----------------------------------+------+-------+
```

Note the simple execution plan. It doesn't get much smoother than that.

[image]